# Server File Updated A newer version is available (OneDrive)

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I have a spreadsheet shared on OneDrive that I maintain, which contains VBA code so it must be opened in the Desktop version. Whenever I open it directly (not through OneDrive) after updates have been made, I get the "*Server File Updated A newer version is available*" message.

Many of the users of this spreadsheet have it open for days on end, and therefore do not see the updates until they close and re-open it.

I am wondering if it is possible to implement some code that periodically checks OneDrive whether a newer version is available and trigger the "*Server File Updated A newer version is available*" pop-up, or at least force a close and reload of the spreadsheet.

This would be a great help for many reasons. Excel certainly does it well enough when I open the file, but I cannot find any way of re-triggering this check.

I hope that makes sense and a simple solution is available.

Darren :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! Yes. It is possible to implement such code. However, that's probably not the answer you're looking for, so, please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you. TL;DR: this isn't a code writing service so you'll have to provide your best shot at it and indicate where you're stuck, then someone will help you fix that specific issue.

Comment: Hi FreeMan. Thank you! You are right, a simple yes is not the answer I was looking for. I have spent a substantial length of time trying to find out whether this is possible, so the fact it can be done is promising. But I am completely at a loss on how to do. I expect it might have something to do with the ThisWorkbook property, but I've no idea.

Comment: This problem occurred in Microsoft SharePoint also.

Answer (score 2):

Solution

Open the windows application Office Upload Center (you can type this in the Windows 10 search to locate it.
Select Settings
Check mark Delete files from the Office Document Cache when they are closed.
This will stop this error happening in the future.
Click Delete cached files to correct the error for the current instance.

1) Search "Upload Center" in Windows 7

2) Upload Center => Settings => Check the box "Deleted files from office document cache when they are closed" and click "Delete Cached files

Comment: This same solution can be applied to Microsoft SharePoint upload failed error also.

Comment: Just note this didn't work for me at all, but this solution did (manually deleting cached files) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/server-file-updated-a-new-version-is-available/901ad39a-bd41-481b-b67c-401800da6231