# Copying Values from one Workbook to a newly created workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please review my code below and tell me what's missing? I thought this would work, but keeps breaking on the copy function. Help greatly appreciated.

Code copies an excel workbook template and renames it in a new directory. Then needs to paste data in from the current workbook to the new one. Copying from this workbook sheet "Site Page", and pasting into NewFileName sheet "Summary".

```
Public NewIntegration As String
    
Sub Copy_One_File()
    
'Variables
Dim TemplateWorkbook As String
Dim NewWorkbook As String
Dim GivenLocation As String
Dim OldFileName As String
Dim NewFileName As String

'Define Strings
TemplateWorkbook = "\\r.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\NOE-RadioEng\Radio\New Build\_2019 NSB Tracker\Integration Reports\Template\TEMPLATE.xlsx"
NewWorkbook = "\\r.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\NOE-RadioEng\Radio\New Build\_2019 NSB Tracker\Integration Reports\TEMPLATENew.xlsx"
GivenLocation = "\\r.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\NOE-RadioEng\Radio\New Build\_2019 NSB Tracker\Integration Reports\"
ReportCreator = "\\r.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\NOE-RadioEng\Radio\New Build\_2019 NSB Tracker\Site_Integration_Report_Creator.xlsm"
OldFileName = "TEMPLATENew.xlsx"
NewFileName = Range("D9").Text 'grab new file name report creator
NewIntegration = GivenLocation & NewFileName 'New location and file name

'Functions
FileCopy TemplateWorkbook, NewWorkbook 'copy file to new location
Name GivenLocation & OldFileName As GivenLocation & NewFileName 'Rename based on H2 cell name

'MsgBox NewIntegration
'Workbooks.Open (NewIntegration)
'MsgBox NewIntegration
'Workbook.Close (NewIntegration)
'MsgBox Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1")

'copy values to new sheet
Worksheets("Site Page").Range("J2").Copy_ Workbooks(NewIntegration).Worksheets("Summary").Range("G1")
End Sub
```

Comment: "keeps breaking on the copy function" is not very descriptive - what happens when you run your code ?"

Comment: @TimWilliams 

Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range

Comment: The destination workbook is not open...

Comment: Also as you're working with multiple workbooks, you should qualify every sheet/range reference with a workbook object.

Comment: How do i qualify with a workbook object?
I'll try with opening it too.

Comment: @TimWilliams I open it, and then it shows the workbook is read only and that a refresh is recommended. How do i fix that so i can write in it?

Comment: If the workbook is read-only then maybe for some reason you don't have write permissions (though you did just create it so...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Dim wbNew As Workbook
'...
'...

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(NewIntegration, ReadOnly:=False)
'what is the source of the copy operation???
Worksheets("Site Page").Range("J2").Copy wbNew.Worksheets("Summary").Range("G1")
wbNew.Close True 'save and close
```

Comment: The source is the sheet running the current macro

Comment: Still getting the same error. Along the top of the newly created and opened workbook shows "REFRESH RECOMMENED A newer version of the file is available on the server" 
Tried your code above, and also tried doing a .refreshAll command, and also did a close then delay and reopen. But still didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any suggestions for that - I've never had that error

Comment: Maybe try the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225677/server-file-updated-a-newer-version-is-available-onedrive